# Distinguish F5 or Open for Browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to distinguish F5 or Open (click on link, paste URL in empty page or new tab, etc.) for Browser?

Why? Because I'd like to improve ergonomics of user interface. In my application some costly computations used to render a page. So page is cached and there is additional button on the page "Recalculate".

I don't like having additional "Recalculate" button when there are exactly the same standard "F5" button.

I control both Server & Client JS, is there any way to be notified about "F5" event?

It is important to detect all "F5" events and not miss it. But it is ok to have sometimes (sometimes but not frequently) additional false "F5" events - when Open Page has been mistakenly detected as "F5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, using `sessionStorage` sounds like your best option.

Something like:

```
var calculatedValues = (function() {
  var savedValues = sessionStorage.getItem("values");
  if (!savedValues) {
    // Do calculations
    var values = {
      result: 10
    };

    savedValues = JSON.stringify(values);
    sessionStorage.setItem("values", savedValues);
  }
  return JSON.parse(savedValues);
}());
```

`sessionStorage` should be unique for every window -- going to to the page under a different window will see no values and recalculate, but pressing `F5` won't.

Some browsers *will* copy session values from one window to another when using `Open in new tab` on a link, but it sounds like that won't be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the `keydown` javascript event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown

You can then use its `key` property to check for F5, and block the browser's reload with `event.preventDefault`

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key == "F5") {
        console.log("F5 Pressed!");
        //do your stuff here
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ANC7e/

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to *stop* `F5` -- just detect it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it seems it's possible to click on the 'F5' button and it won't be detected.